# List with Associated Detail Box GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm working in C# / WPF and I'm trying to develop a Window that has the following layout:

[image]

The idea is that you click each item in the datagrid and see associated details of that item in a control below the datagrid. I'm just not sure what kind of control would house the expanded details. Really my question is around options for how achieve this kind of UI, as I'm a novice at WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neat and fairly easy solution would be to have two separate Views. One embedded in the other. The grid with listed items is your main View. The details panel is second View embedded in the first one.

To communicate which item is selected and which details should be displayed you are using binding. On the panel displaying details you are using `DataContext` and bind to it an item selected on the grid. And, on the grid, to communicate which item has been selected you are using `SelectedValue`.

Below some sample that should give you an idea what's the relation between the Views.

```
<Window
 ...
xmlns:View="clr-namespace:SampleProject.View"
 ...
/>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
    <!-- Let's assume that your second view is defined in the View folder -->
    <View:DetailsView DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    ...
```

The `Items` is a collection of the products you want to display in the `DataGrid`. It should be implemented in the ViewModel of your main View. The `SelectedItem` is a property on the ViewModel.

Note that the sample is only to give you an idea what's the structure of solution might be but it's far from a complete solution. Still, hope it will help you to understand how to continue with your project.

Main point is that the communication between panels is done by use of binding to DataContext (on the `DetailsView`) and to SelectedValue (on the grid).